# How to update values in a column MySQL database with data in a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, database, csv

I have a python script that stores information in a csv file. The columns are **Name,Time Left, Date,ID** I have a MySql database with the following columns: **Name, Time Entered, Time Left, Date, ID**

Time left is set to null. I am using one python script with pandas to update the rest of the rows. In a different script I want to update the Time Left column with the data I have in my CSV file if the IDs match (ID is a primary key).

I am unable to figure out how to do this. I have attached the code below for what I essentially want:

```
#loop through the data frame
        for i,row in empdata.iterrows():
            rowValue = row['ID']
            leaveTime = row['Time Left']
            sql = "UPDATE studentInfo SET `Time Left` = rowValue WHERE ID = leaveTime;"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            print("Record inserted")
            conn.commit()
        print("Completed!")
except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
```

The data in rowValue and leaveTime are in my CSV file and I want to use them to update my database table after iterating through the values.

Any advice will be really appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar nor having any knowledge of updating data table directly from CSV file but might I suggest that you import the CSV file as temp table then use that to do `UPDATE .. JOIN`?

Comment: I suggest you check out the approach provided by the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827402/update-an-existing-sql-table-based-on-content-from-an-external-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

Consider iterating through [**`csv.DictReader`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), avoiding pandas, and run [`executemany`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) on list of tuples. (Also, you may need to flip row values to map positionally to `%s` placeholders).

```py
import csv
...

# PREPARED STATEMENT  WITH PARAM PLACEHOLDERS
sql = "UPDATE studentInfo SET `Time Left` = %s WHERE ID = %s;"

# READ CSV WITH HEADERS TO LIST OF TUPLES
with open("mydata.csv", "r", newline="") as f:
    dr = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = [(row['Time Left'], row['ID']) for row in dr]

# EXECUTE QUERY AND BIND PARAMS TO PLACEHOLDERS
cursor.executemany(sql, data)
conn.commit()
```

---

To avoid the iteration of CSV rows especially if very large (i.e., hundreds of thousands to millions), consider [**`LOAD DATA`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) from a csv into a temporary table (that persists only during session) and then run a single `UPDATE` +`JOIN` query without parameters. Note: Adjust data types and load data settings to match actual data.

```py
sql = """CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_data (
             Id INTEGER,
             `Time Left` DATETIME
         )
      """
cur.execute(sql)

sql = """LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/test.txt'
         INTO TABLE temp_data
         IGNORE 1 LINES
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
         LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
      """
cur.execute(sql)


sql = """UPDATE studentInfo s
         INNER JOIN temp_data t
            ON s.Id = t.Id
         SET `Time Left` = `Time Left`
      """
cur.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: This made a lot of sense and works! Thanks for your input - had a few SQL related errors which I figured out and now the program is doing exactly what I need. The data set is not too big but using LOAD DATA has been much more straight forward than pandas for this part. Really appreciate your help ! :)